# Getting a MySQL Query to save as a global Variable is C

Tags: mysql, c

I am having issues getting a function to run and having the results of a MySQL query to be saved as a variable that other functions can use and call upon. I know the results get read from the table as a string. I was able to do this fine when getting the results and converting it to a float and then passing the results to a pointer. But I can not seem to figure out how to get the results as a string, and compare it with another string to see if they match or do not. No matter what I have tried to do, I can not seem to get a value to be saved as a string to a variable outside the function.

Here is the code of how I got it to work as a float:

(Outside the main function)

```
float temperature_reading;
float *p_temperature_reading= &temperature_reading;
float humidity_reading;
float *p_humidity_reading= &humidity_reading;
```

The function I have working with the float, that I can save to a global variable

```
void MIA_get_current_temperature()
{

    const char *query = "SELECT Temperature, Humidity FROM `temperature` WHERE Type='Current_Temperature'";

    if (mysql_query(conn, query) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        MYSQL_RES *query_results = mysql_store_result(conn);
        if (query_results) 
        { // make sure there *are* results..
            MYSQL_ROW row;

            while((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)
            {

                float f = row[0] ? atof(row[0]) : 0.0f;
                float h = row[1] ? atof(row[1]) : 0.0f;

                *p_temperature_reading = f;
                *p_humidity_reading = h;

                printf("The Temp & Hum from DB is: %.1f & %.1f\n", *p_temperature_reading,*p_humidity_reading);    
            }

        /* Free results when done */
        mysql_free_result(query_results);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function  I can not get to work:

(Outside main Function)

```
 char ac_mode[256];
 char *p_ac_mode = &ac_mode[256];
```

Function:

```
void MIA_get_desired_temperature()
 {

    const char *query = "SELECT Mode, Desired_Temperature, Threshold FROM `ac_mode` WHERE Status='ON'";

    if (mysql_query(conn, query) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        MYSQL_RES *query_results = mysql_store_result(conn);
        if (query_results) 
        { // make sure there *are* results..
            MYSQL_ROW row;

            while((row = mysql_fetch_row(query_results)) !=0)
            {

                char *ac = row[0] ? row[0] : "NULL";
                float desired_temperature = row[1] ? atof(row[1]) : 0.0f;
                int threshold = row[2] ? atof(row[2]) : 0.0f;

                *p_ac_mode = *ac;
                *p_desired_temperature = desired_temperature;  
                *p_threshold=threshold;

            }

        /* Free results when done */
        mysql_free_result(query_results);
        }
    }
}
```

char *ac is where I want the string to be stored.

Comment: "No matter what I have tried..". Please show what you have tried for the string version. Without that we can't tell you what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @kaylum I edited the posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
char *p_ac_mode = &ac_mode[256];
```

..is incorrect.  You're probably trying to declare a pointer to the array (or maybe to its contents)... what you're actually doing is declaring a `char *` that points at the first byte *after* the array `ac_mode`.  The `[256]` here isn't indicating that `ac_mode` has 256 elements, it's indexing the array to get element 256 (which would be the 257th char in the array if it were big enough -- but it's not, so it's outside the array).  You're then taking the address of that out-of-bounds `char` and assign it to `p_ac_mode`, so that `p_ac_mode` to points to it.

To point `p_ac_mode` at the array contents, you'd just use `char *p_ac_mode = ac_mode;` (which makes it a `char *` pointing at the first `char` in the array).  To get a pointer to the array itself, you'd use `char (*p_ac_mode)[256] = &ac_mode;`, which makes it a pointer to a 256-element array of `char`.  In any case there's no need for `p_ac_mode` at all, because you can access the array through `ac_mode` directly in all the same places, and the bare array name `ac_mode` will usually decay to a pointer to its first `char` anyway.

---

With this line:

```
                *p_ac_mode = *ac;
```

..you're copying the first `char` from string `ac` to the first `char` *after* `ac_mode` (because that's what `p_ac_mode` points to, as explained above).  I suspect you're actually trying to assign the whole `ac` string's contents to `ac_mode` via `p_ac_mode` -- but that won't work for a few reasons.

An array is actually a block of memory holding a series of values of the same type.  Although in many situations the array name will decay to a pointer (the address of the array's first element), the array itself is the block of memory and not the pointer.  You can't just assign a pointer (new address) to the array, and array contents aren't automatically copied this way either. The contents need to be copied over element by element, or using a function that copies the contents.

What you need to do is copy the contents of the string from your query results into the `ac_mode` array with `strcpy()` or similar.  Just changing this line:

```
                *p_ac_mode = *ac;
```

to this:

```
                strcpy(ac_mode, ac);
```

...would do that.

Comment: so I changed the like *p_ac_mode = *ac; to   strcpy(ac_mode, ac);, but now I get the error " warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcpy' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]" and "warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy' [enabled by default]"

Comment: also regarding char ac_mode[256]; char *p_ac_mode = &ac_mode[256];  I can just get ride of char *p_ac_mode, and also for the ac_mode[256], do I keep the [256]? I thought I had to assign a size to the array.

Comment: @Vlad you need to add `#include <string.h>` near the top of your source file to get the `strcpy()` prototype.  That should work and get rid of the "implicit declaration" warning.

Comment: @Vlad When you first declare `ac_mode`, you *do* use the `[256]` to give the array size... but only in the declaration -- after that, the brackets are for indexing and not specifying the size.

Comment: okay I totally forgot to include the string.h header file. but what about the variables: char ac_mode[256]; char *p_ac_mode = &ac_mode[256]? What do I need to set them outside the main function to? Since you said I can get ride of the pointer (p_ac_mode)

Comment: @Vlad Not sure what you mean... you can just use the array name, `ac_mode`, as a `char *` to access the string.  `ac_mode` by itself is (usually) equivalent to `&ac_mode[0]` -- it gives a pointer to the characters in the array... and since it's global you can use that anywhere in the file past where you declare it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102032/discussion-between-dmitri-and-vlad).

Comment: I was wonderng if you can check out my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904422/mysql-query-select-fields-where-time-value-in-table-is-equal-to-current-time/41946869#41946869 , ot open a chat. I have gotten better with c but i am having in interesting issue with C and MySql

Answer (score 1):

You need to use strcpy in your MIA_get_desired_temperature function. Also, you don't need the pointer p_ac_mode.  Just copy into ac_mode directly.

```
strcpy(ac_mode, ac);
```